# Overloading ostream of vector template with iterator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, ostream

**Why I can't use iterator in ostream overloading?**

If I use the same declaration using iterative approach it works.

Consider the following code:

```
template <class T>
class List {
    template <class U>
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const List<U> &rhs);
private:
    vector<T> v;
};

template<class U>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const List<U>& rhs)
{
    vector<U>::iterator it = rhs.v.begin();
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    List<int> list;
    cout << list << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If C++11 is available for your target platform, you may want to declare the iterator's type as `auto`, so the compiler can deduce the correct type for you.  It's a lot easier to type, in both senses of the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Note that `rhs` is declared as reference to `const`, then `rhs.v` will be `const` too, then `rhs.v.begin()` will return a `std::vector<U>::const_iterator`, which can't be converted to `std::vector<U>::iterator` directly.
2. You should use [typename](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) for [dependent type names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

So change it to

```
typename vector<U>::const_iterator it = rhs.v.begin();
```

BTW: `void main()` should be `int main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
typename vector<U>::const_iterator it = rhs.v.begin();
```

If your `rsh` is `const`, you should use a `const_iterator`